# Your app's Data safety section will be invalidated and state "No information available"

Tags: google-play-console, privacy, privacy-policy

A week before I uploaded an application **CV Maker** that input user data like *name, phone, email, educational information, address e.t.c* and store to local storage as **json**. Data is only stored on local storage neither shared with anyone nor uploaded to server (even no server connected)  Internet is only used for ads  [plat store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appcart.cv_maker)

While publishing to play console following info is given

- Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types? =
  yes
- Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit? =
  no
- Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted?
  = yes

And this

- Is this data collected, shared, or both? = Collected
- Is this data processed ephemerally? = yes
- Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it's collected? = Users can choose whether this data is collected
- Why is this user data collected? = check App functionality

But the Issue is
mail screenshot [[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfAoK.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfAoK.png)

Comment: Sounds like you're collecting IDs and Google wonders why you need those just to "check app functionality".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably You are using google mobile ads!
if yes then you must need to say yes for Does your app use advertising ID? and also check for **Advertising or marketing**

Steps to Solve isse are
1- Goto play console
2- Select Application
3- Goto app Content
4- Choose Advertising ID
5- click yes for Does your app use advertising ID?
6- check Advertising or marketing
7- click save

Answer (score 1):

The Data Safety form is incorrect.

Possible fixes:

- State that you collect "Device or other IDs" at Step 3 Data types
- Atp Step 4 describe why and how the "Device or other IDs" data types are collected:

  - Not processed ephemerally. Ephemerally means that the data is stored only in memory.
  - Data collection is required
  - Collected for "App functionality", "Account management" etc., whatever best describes your use case for data collection